# PostgreSQL multiplication of columns

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, null, aggregate-functions

I have Postgres database and I have to multiply column by column like this:

```
SELECT SUM(column1*column2) AS res (...)
```

And the result is `0`. Both columns are `real` type.
But the multiplication operator works great when I do:

```
SELECT SUM(column * 100) AS res (...)
```

Is it possible to do arithmetics using columns in PostgreSQL?

Comment: how do you check that res = 0? have you tried to execute query in pgAdmin? do you have some example input?

Comment: Do you have any `NULL` values or `0` in either of the columns? Post a complete query and sample values, please. You can do pretty much any arithmetic operation with columns. There must be some kind of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This query works just fine:

```
SELECT SUM(column1 * column2) AS res
FROM   tbl;
```

If your result `res` is `0`, then you must have:

- `0` in one or both of the columns and none of them `NULL` in at least one row.
- `0` or `NULL` in one or both of the columns for every other selected row.

Or there is some other trivial misunderstanding involved. Maybe you are confusing your column alias `res` with `result`?

Comment: Well, you are right :) It worsk fine, but there can't be 0 in none of the rows.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a subquery

```
SELECT
  SUM(subq.multiplied_column)
FROM (
  SELECT
    column1 * column2 AS multiplied_column
  FROM
    table
) as subq
```

Also Take care of NULL values. If some value from column1 or column2 is NULL then all the result of SUM() can be NULL, and depending on the language you are using and the connection library, you can see 0 as a result instead of NULL.

Comment: This answer is wrong. A subquery is absolutely not necessary. @agna must have stumbled over some other problem. Also, the aggregate function [`sum()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) ignores `NULL` values when adding up values from qualifying rows. The result can only be NULL if a) all columns are `NULL` (in this case: at least one of the two columns being multiplied in every row) or b) no row is selected.